# How to orderBy desc UTC time stamp column in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, unix-timestamp

I need to order by desc for specific column in my spark data frame .
For example here is the date time  format that i want to reorder

```
"2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00"
"2017-11-21T12:18:55+00:00"
"2017-11-21T11:41:14+00:00"
```

This is what i am doing to reorder

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Source_organizationId", "Source_sourceId").orderBy(unix_timestamp($"TimeStamp", "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD").cast("timestamp").desc) 

val latestForEachKey = finaldf.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec))
latestForEachKey.show(false)
```

Here is the output

```
+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+----+
|DataPartition     |TimeStamp                |Source_organizationId|Source_sourceId|FilingDateTime           |SourceTypeCode|DocumentId|Dcn      |DocFormat|StatementDate            |IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|ContainsPreliminaryData|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|ContainsRestatement|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|ThirdPartySourceCode|ThirdPartySourcePriority|SourceTypeId|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|FFAction|!||rank|
+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+----+
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T10:48:00+00:00|5046043341           |106            |1997-05-12T12:00:00+00:00|10Q           |2426194   |null     |null     |1997-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |1997-03-31T00:00:00+00:00  |0.22223                   |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-05-04T09:46:05+00:00|4295907168           |450            |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|ESGWEB        |null      |null     |null     |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|true                     |false                  |null                       |1.0                       |false              |0                      |ATD                 |null                    |1002198005  |null                  |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:27:19+00:00|4298009288           |11             |2006-10-12T12:00:00+00:00|10K           |7740531   |null     |ASFILED  |2006-07-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2006-07-31T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:27:19+00:00|4298009288           |44             |2007-06-07T12:00:10+00:00|10Q           |null      |07905477 |ASFILED  |2007-04-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2007-04-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T10:01:29+00:00|5046043341           |97             |1999-08-12T16:00:00+00:00|10Q           |null      |null     |null     |1999-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |1999-06-30T00:00:00+00:00  |0.33334                   |false              |-240                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00|4295904170           |364            |2017-08-08T17:00:00+00:00|10Q           |null      |null     |null     |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:18:55+00:00|4295904170           |364            |2017-08-08T17:00:00+00:00|10Q           |null      |null     |null     |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T11:41:14+00:00|4295904170           |364            |2017-08-08T17:00:00+00:00|10Q           |null      |null     |null     |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T11:32:25+00:00|5046043341           |82             |2004-08-09T12:00:00+00:00|10Q           |3932989   |null     |null     |2004-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2004-06-30T00:00:00+00:00  |0.5                       |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T11:20:05+00:00|5046043341           |82             |2004-08-09T12:00:00+00:00|10Q           |3932989   |null     |null     |2004-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2004-06-30T00:00:00+00:00  |0.5                       |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T11:05:50+00:00|5046043341           |76             |2006-05-09T16:00:00+00:00|10Q           |7165449   |null     |ASFILED  |2006-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2006-03-31T00:00:00+00:00  |0.5                       |false              |-240                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T10:01:29+00:00|5046043341           |98             |1999-05-12T16:00:00+00:00|10Q           |2429120   |null     |null     |1999-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |1999-03-31T00:00:00+00:00  |0.33334                   |false              |-240                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|Japan             |2017-04-25T07:34:37+00:00|4295876606           |159            |2017-01-01T03:00:00+00:00|JPNINR        |null      |null     |null     |2016-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2016-12-31T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |540                    |SS                  |1                       |3012418     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T11:20:05+00:00|5046043341           |80             |2005-05-09T12:00:00+00:00|10Q           |4376029   |null     |null     |2005-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2005-03-31T00:00:00+00:00  |0.5                       |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:27:19+00:00|4298009288           |12             |2006-10-12T12:00:10+00:00|10K           |null      |061140985|ASFILED  |2006-07-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2006-07-31T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:28:44+00:00|4298009288           |29             |2010-03-10T17:00:10+00:00|10Q           |null      |10669005 |ASFILED  |2010-01-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2010-01-31T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:27:19+00:00|4298009288           |43             |2007-06-07T12:00:00+00:00|10Q           |8753978   |null     |ASFILED  |2007-04-30T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2007-04-30T00:00:00+00:00  |1.0                       |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T10:48:00+00:00|5046043341           |110            |1996-05-15T12:00:00+00:00|10Q           |null      |null     |null     |1996-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|true                     |false                  |1996-03-31T00:00:00+00:00  |0.22223                   |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011836     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T10:48:00+00:00|5046043341           |107            |1997-03-31T12:00:00+00:00|10K           |null      |null     |null     |1996-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|true                     |false                  |1996-12-31T00:00:00+00:00  |0.22223                   |false              |0                      |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T11:05:50+00:00|5046043341           |14             |2006-03-15T17:00:00+00:00|10K           |6943116   |null     |ASFILED  |2005-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |2005-12-31T00:00:00+00:00  |0.5                       |false              |-300                   |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |I|!|       |1   |
+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+----+
```

For example row (`4295904170           |364`) has same `rank` as last column in data frame  which is wrong .

If sorting works then rank will change to 3,2,1

Comment: didn't it work ? whats the issue?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan i am not getting sorted value ...

Comment: try row_number instead of rank().

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes its working ..Thank you